# nested list in python3 minesweeper sorting doesn't work correctly

Tags: python

Ok guys so i got some help from you earlier. But right now i am banging my head against the table.

The code works 'kinda'. But i don't want the last numbers of the list to add to the first number of another list. Hard for me to explain so i´ll show you further down!

all the zeroes adjacent to the 'M'´s is supposed to change. but some are getting too high numbers.

heres the code:

```
hiddenfield =  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 'M'],
            [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 'M', 'M', 'M'],
            [0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M'],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 'M', 0, 0, 0],
            ['M', 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 'M', 'M', 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'M'],
            ['M', 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0]] 



def update_numbers(x, y, hiddenfield):
    try:
        if hiddenfield[x][y] != 'M':
            hiddenfield[x][y] += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass

def numbersinhiddefield(indexes):
    indexes = [[i,j] for i,row in enumerate(indexes) for j,elem in enumerate(row) if elem == 'M']
    loop = 0
    while loop < len(indexes):
        update_numbers(indexes[loop][0]+1,indexes[loop][1], hiddenfield)
        update_numbers(indexes[loop][0]-1,indexes[loop][1], hiddenfield)
        update_numbers(indexes[loop][0],indexes[loop][1]+1, hiddenfield)
        update_numbers(indexes[loop][0],indexes[loop][1]-1, hiddenfield)
        update_numbers(indexes[loop][0]+1,indexes[loop][1]+1, hiddenfield)
        update_numbers(indexes[loop][0]-1,indexes[loop][1]-1, hiddenfield)
        update_numbers(indexes[loop][0]+1,indexes[loop][1]-1, hiddenfield)
        update_numbers(indexes[loop][0]-1,indexes[loop][1]+1, hiddenfield)
        loop += 1

def showMineFieldHidden(hiddenfield):
    border = list(range(0,len(hiddenfield)))
    row = [' ']+border
    i = 0
    for rows in [border]+hiddenfield:
        print(row[i], end=' ')
        i += 1
        for lines in rows:
            print(lines, end=' ')
        print()

numbersinhiddefield(hiddenfield)

showMineFieldHidden(hiddenfield)
```

But the thing i get out isn't just right:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 0 0 1 1 2 M 2 2 4 M 
1 0 1 2 M 3 2 3 M M M 
2 0 1 M 4 M 2 2 M 5 M 
3 0 2 2 5 M 3 1 1 2 1 
4 0 1 M 4 M 4 2 1 0 0 
5 1 2 3 M 4 M M 2 1 1 
6 M 1 3 M 4 2 3 M 1 1 
7 2 3 4 M 3 1 1 1 2 2 
8 2 M M 4 M 1 0 1 2 M 
9 M 3 3 M 3 2 1 1 M 4 <-- this is supposed to be a 2.
            ^
            this is supposed to be a 1 and the one next to it a zero
```

I think it is adding from the borders to the lower list?

Would appreciate som help!

Comment: Python *wraps* list indexes at 0, more exactly`l[-1]` is the last element of the list `l`. So if you are not cautious enough with negative indexes bad things can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you have an 'M' in row `0` you use that to add to the count for row `-1`. An index of `-1` is an alternate way to refer to the last row. Similary for column `0` you add to the count for column `-1`.

This means that an 'M' on the top row counts for the bottom row, and an 'M' in the left column counts for the right column.

If you modify `updatenumbers()` to range check the coordinates you should be able to avoid the double counting. That might also look cleaner than the exception handling.

```
def update_numbers(x, y, hiddenfield):
    if 0 <= x < len(hiddenfield) and 0 <= y < len(hiddenfield[x]):
        if hiddenfield[x][y] != 'M':
            hiddenfield[x][y] += 1
```